# Há crase em "Ela foi submetida a agressão verbal"?

Tags: crase

> (sub.me.ter)
>
> v.
>
> 1. Fazer que se renda ou obedeça, ou render-se, obedecer. [td. : Os Aliados submeteram a Alemanha] [tdr. + a : submeter os filhos à
>      disciplina.: submeter -se à lei] [tdi. : Aquela escrava não se
>      submetia ao feitor]
> 2. Tornar(-se) alvo ou objeto de. [tdr. + a : Submeteu sua tese à apreciação do orientador.: submeter -se a um exame médico] [tdi. :
>      Submeteu ao diretor a minuta do relatório]

http://www.aulete.com.br/submeter

> Nas orações em que aparecem o termo regido pela preposição "a"
>   introduzindo um objeto indireto, o acento grave indicativo da crase é
>   obrigatório.

http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/minigramatica/mini/acraseeoobjetoindireto.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende.  Se a agressão verbal já foi citada antes, com seus detalhes e, por exemplo, você está se referindo à consequência, há crase porque **é uma agressão específica** e existe o artigo "a" e a preposição "a".  Mas se a frase refere-se a **agressões de um modo geral**, não existe o artigo definido, apenas a preposição, e não há crase.

ex:

> - Depois que foi submetida à agressão verbal citada anteriormente, ela ficou muito nervosa.
> - Ela foi submetida a agressão verbal e espancamento.
> - Ela foi submetida ao castigo que mereceu.
> - Ela foi submetida a castigo jamais visto.

Compare:

> - Sua camisa está cheirando a gasolina.
> - Sua camisa está cheirando a álcool.
> - Sua camisa está cheirando à gasolina que eu derramei sobra a mesa.
> - Sua camisa está cheirando ao álcool que vazou da garrafa.

Comment: *comapare => compare